# Whats the use of random question at Blogger?

Tags: blogger

While updating my blogger profile, I noticed the "random question" on my profile with a comment you must "save your profile to get a new question". I can't find any relevant sources why a random question is asked over there? What's the main use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a way to inspire you to add useful/interesting information to your Blogger Profile. Certainly you've seen enough profiles that are nothing but a name?